# asp.net MVC 2 Database localization. Multilang app

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, localization, globalization

I have a multilanggual website. I would like to store Locatilzation in database instead of ressource file.

If somebody has good tutorial or documentation about that, I appreciate to access these doc.

Comment: what DB? SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best place to start is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905797.aspx  I have followed this process in a number of projects very successfully

Comment: The articles approach deals with (web forms) ASP .Net 2.0. Can it be used with MVC 3 as well?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Data Driven Resource provider from Rick Strahl](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/695968.aspx)

Comment: This is not MVC implementation

Comment: @doganak: The OP is asking for tutorials and documentation, surely this project is a good start for that. And the DB resource provider is common for all ASP.net